# How can I abstractify my GSON models? **ClassCastException**

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, gson

I am trying to make a module which should be able to convert data that I get from a GraphQL API to kotlin using GSON.

I have an interface that I want to abstractify, So that it can handle more than one single ModelType as it does right now.

```kotlin
data class Response(val data: Data, val errors: MutableList<GQLError>)
data class GQLError(val message: String)
data class Data(val events: MutableList<Event>)

interface ICache : IObservable {
    val url: String

    var content: MutableList<Event>

    fun cache(query: GQL) {
        println(query)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response: Response = postStuff(query, url)
            launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                this@ICache.content = response.data.events
                sendUpdateEvent()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I was thinking to change it so that it will look something like  this:

```kotlin
data class Response<T>(val data: T, val errors: MutableList<GQLError>)
data class GQLError(val message: String)
data class EventList(val events: MutableList<Event>)

interface ICache<T> : IObservable {
    val url: String

    var content: T

    fun cache(query: GQL) {
        println(query)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val response: Response<T> = postStuff(query, url)
            launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                this@ICache.content = response.data
                sendUpdateEvent()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then when I get concrete I can do than in a class for itself:

```kotlin
object ConcreteEvents : ICache<T> {
    override val url: String = "https://example.com/gql-api"
    override var content = EventList(ArrayList())
    override val observers: ArrayList<IObserver> = ArrayList()
}
```

That way when I run

```kotlin
ConcreteEvents.cache()
```

Then my content should be set. But I get an error:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to dtu.android.moroapp.observer.EventList`

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: dtu.android.moroapp, PID: 21907
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to dtu.android.moroapp.observer.EventList
        at dtu.android.moroapp.observer.ConcreteEvents.setContent(ConcreteEvents.kt:11)
        at dtu.android.moroapp.observer.ICache$cache$1$1.invokeSuspend(ICache.kt:21)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

My postStuff function looks like this:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> postStuff(query: Any, url: String): T{
    val req = URL(url)
    val con = req.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    con.requestMethod = "POST"
    con.connectTimeout = 30000
    con.doOutput = true
    val json = Gson().toJson(query)
    val data = (json).toByteArray()
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
    val request = DataOutputStream(con.outputStream)
    request.write(data)
    request.flush()
    con.inputStream.bufferedReader().use {
        val response = StringBuffer()
        var inputLine = it.readLine()
        while (inputLine != null) {
            response.append(inputLine)
            inputLine = it.readLine()
        }
        return Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), T::class.java)
    }
}
```

I tried to do `TypeToken` instead of `T::class.java` and I even tried to define the typetoken in the concrete class and pass it through the parameters, but it didnt change anything. I always get the same exception.

When I debug the program, then I can see that `Response` are converted fine, but the value `data` in `Response` is returned as a `LinkedTreeMap`

[image]

Something goes wrong in that conversion.. I have no idea what?. Please help me!

Thank you in advance, and have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that I had to specifically define the type, 100% concrete for GSON to work properly.

So my solution was to pass the `Type` into the parameter all the way from `ConcreteEvents` like this

```kotlin
object :TypeToken<Response<EventList>>(){}.type
```

And then make all the generics functions receive a type in the parameter.